# Android annotation at runtime

Tags: android, annotations

I want to annotate a list of classes with a custom annotation, which I need at runtime.

My annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    String value() default "defaultValue";
}
```

My custom class is:

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class MyClass {
}
```

Now, I want to read the annotation from a class name, which I has as string. Code is without error handling (for easy handling):

```
String className = "com.example.MyClass";
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
Annotation[] annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(); // is empty
```

Why is **clazz.getAnnotation()** empty? Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code - it works for me.
Only need to call getAnnotation**s**()

The issue is definitely out of code you posted.